# displaying calender using jquery

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I m trying to display calendar when I click on calendar icon.but issue i m facing is when i click on any of the other calendar icons  on the page it opens only this particular calendar propertyPurchaseDate0.

```
    $("div").on("click","i.fa-calendar", function(){
                debugger;
                $("input#propertyPurchaseDate0").focus();
            }); 

    $("div").on("click","i.fa-calendar", function(){
                debugger;
                $("input#lastValuationDate0").focus();
            }); 



    <div class="table-row" id="div1">
            <div class="table-cell width-12percent margin-top-5px">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PurchaseDate)
            </div>

            <div class="table-cell width-12percent margin-top-5px">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PurchaseDate, new { id = "propertyPurchaseDate" + Model.AccountId, @class = "propertypurchaseDate", @onchange = "SetDate(this)" })
            </div>
        </div>



datetime.cshtml:

@model DateTime?

@{
    var dateFormat = Utils.DefaultDateFormat;
    var jsDateFormat = dateFormat.Replace("MM", "mm");
    var dateString = Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.Date.ToString(dateFormat) : "";
}

<div class="row collapse date" data-date="@dateString" data-date-format="@jsDateFormat">
    <div class="small-10 columns no-padding">
        <input id="@ViewData["id"]" type="text"
               value="@dateString"
               placeholder="@jsDateFormat"
               class="@ViewData["class"]"
               name="@Html.NameForModel()"
               onchange="@ViewData["onchange"]" />
    </div>
    <div class="small-2 columns no-padding" >
        <span class="postfix add-on"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the jquery selector you are using is a `div` for both the datepicker. You have to give unique `id` for your `div` and then use the `click` function on them. Try this:

```
 $("#div2").on("click","i.fa-calendar", function(){
                debugger;
                $("input#propertyPurchaseDate0").focus();
            }); 

    $("#div3").on("click","i.fa-calendar", function(){
                debugger;
                $("input#lastValuationDate0").focus();
            }); 



    <div class="table-row" id="div1">
            <div id="div2" class="table-cell width-12percent margin-top-5px">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PurchaseDate)
            </div>

            <div id="div3" class="table-cell width-12percent margin-top-5px">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PurchaseDate, new { id = "propertyPurchaseDate" + Model.AccountId, @class = "propertypurchaseDate", @onchange = "SetDate(this)" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The outside and inside div were both given same id div1 by me. I changed it. Try it again.

Comment: So you mean that when you click on the div the focus is not coming to the calendar?

Comment: when i click on the calender icon for any other date also on the page,it is opening this particular calendar only

Comment: These ID's "propertyPurchaseDate0" and "lastValuationDate0" are correct? I mean are these coming same as in F12??

Comment: Another thing when you use model.PurchaseDate what is the ID for that datepicker in F12, its not "lastValuationDate0" i think... And when you do model => model.PurchaseDate, new { id = "propertyPurchaseDate" + Model.AccountId, then your datepicker Id is "propertyPurchaseDate0" ???

Comment: thoroughly check your Ids and the selectors you are using. The problem lies there.